# How can I load an external URL into my webview?

Tags: objective-c, cordova, webview

I use a Cordova project (Xcode) with onesignal plugin. 
When notification is clicked, I want to load the webview with target URL.

First approcha was bad: it was opening external Safari browser.

Second approach:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
      if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]])
      {
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
        UIWebView webView = (UIWebView )view;
        NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
        [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
        [webView reload];
      }
    }
```

It just gives me black screen.

How can I load an external URL into my webview Cordova with Xcode?

Comment: Do you have any errors in Xcode ?

Comment: Another solution could be to send the URL in the message. And then intercept it with `notificationOpenedCallback` and open the URL in the app the InAppBrowser plugin.

Comment: If it really is a black screen, that sounds like a view layout problem, i.e. the web view isn't taking up any space, either because it is hidden, because the bounds haven't been set correctly (or at all), or because of an AutoLayout problem of some kind.  If you meant "blank" (as in a web view with a white background and a search box), then I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: No errors in xcode

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about keeping the URL within the app, you could simply do a

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];`